# emulate right click when you click

Tags: right-click, emulation

Right clicking my mouse brings up several choices, one being "open link in new window"

Now, I would like to enter some code that when someone left-clicks on a link, emulates exactly the right click option mentioned.

I've looked everywhere...

is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you bit a little bit more specific? What platform would you like this to work on? What programming language? Some general background, etc.

Comment: Hi The page is written mostly in css/html with a javascript or two. Best to see it in action: http://pintotours.net/Americas/DomRepublic/StoDomingo.php  Click on any of the central button links to open the popup. Then go to the map, half-way down, and clicj again. In Opera the map will appear under the popup (in other browsers on top as should be). Now if you try to open the map in opera by right clicking and choosing "open link in new window" it opens as I want it. How can I get round this problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute _target="blank" will open in a new tab or window.

```html
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">My Link</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, looks like I answered your question in the wrong place: above.

Comment: The link in the popup is launched via a target="_blank". In all browsers the new full page opens over the smaller popup. In Opera, it opens under, with the popup that must stay open over the full page. I've tried various html like target="_top" and some onclick and other scripts I found online but cannot get it to work.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. I think target="_blank" is going to be the closest you can get. It's browser functionality, and the browser chooses what to do when it receives the command.